# How to show multiple images in ImageView

Tags: android

I want to show image with text by rowwise.here is my xml file

and In RowItem Class contains i m seting Bit Map object

Now i m using hardcoded String array but i want to set using String array of URL
I fetch this url form network using httpconnection also i m added permisions in andoridManifest.xml file

i m confusing i m not geting any correct solution plz help me

i reffer this url for showing images
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/
i want to do same only use url rather than hardcoded images

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#3399FF"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Java code

```
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class BdaylistActivity extends Activity implements
            OnItemClickListener {
        private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
         ListView listView;
            List<RowItem> rowItems;



        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bdaylist);


            m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,    
                    "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
            new BirthdayTask().execute("https://gdirectoryqa.appspot.com/gDirectory/get_user_profile.htm");


        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("BDay", true);
                   startActivity(intent);
        }


        class BirthdayTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                String responseString = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        out.close();
                        responseString = out.toString();
                    } else{
                        //Closes the connection.
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    //TODO Handle problems..
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return responseString;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                JSONArray jArr;
                ArrayList<String> firstLastNames=new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<Integer> images=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                try {
                    jArr = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++) {
                        JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);
                        JSONObject userGeneralInfoArray = jArr.getJSONObject(count).getJSONObject("userGeneralInfo"); 
                        firstLastNames.add(userGeneralInfoArray.getString("firstName")+" "+userGeneralInfoArray.getString("lastName"));
                        images.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    }

                    System.out.println("firstName="+firstLastNames);
                    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

                    if(firstLastNames.size() == 0){
                        firstLastNames.add("No Results");
                        images.add(1);
                    }
                    String[] images=new String[]{"http://lh6.ggpht.com/K9UV3dTXSNPk9bGvshrOPPwIl7ExDUEpG2SzdOv8tGBqX4QFpyLRWgvFiyjZ29LNfrBMQPiTVdy14b7eOrodWsLNJDl4zGQ","http://lh6.ggpht.com/K9UV3dTXSNPk9bGvshrOPPwIl7ExDUEpG2SzdOv8tGBqX4QFpyLRWgvFiyjZ29LNfrBMQPiTVdy14b7eOrodWsLNJDl4zGQ","http://theopentutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png"};
                    for (int i = 0; i < firstLastNames.size(); i++) {
                        RowItem item = new RowItem(images.get(i), null, firstLastNames.get(i));
                        rowItems.add(item);
                    }

                    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(BdaylistActivity.this,
                            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(BdaylistActivity.this);
                    m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this might help.

When ever I want to fetch an image from the internet, and have it shown in my android application, I always use "Aquery"

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

It's fast, easy to use, and very little code is needed to make the magic happen. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In you CustomListViewAdapter class method

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
```

holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

```
    return convertView;
}
```

holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

In this line at first convert url image to bitmap
  [converting image from url to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969526/converting-image-from-url-to-bitmap)
then set this bitmap in imageview

holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)

Comment: Bitmap bitMap=DownloadImage(rowItem.getImageurl());
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap); i added this line but not showing

Comment: At first Check Bitmap return null or not because it help me to understand the problem that it happen for convert image url to bitmap or other.